# TypeScript -> JavaScript for browser: exports/require statements

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to switch from JavaScript to TypeScript for our web app's scripts. However, when generating the JavaScript it always puts the following lines on top of the script:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var $ = require("jquery");
```

I receive browser errors for this. How to prevent TypeScript from doing so?

I read [TypeScript: Avoid require statements in compiled JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127953/typescript-avoid-require-statements-in-compiled-javascript) but it can't be the answer to switch to "any", this forfeits the whole TypeScript idea.

I also read [Typescript importing exported class emits require(...) which produces browser errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241988/typescript-importing-exported-class-emits-require-which-produces-browser-er) but this still generates the `<reference...` stuff into the JS file, which is also not what I want.

How to create "clean" JS files?

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

My gulp call is:

```
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
...
var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");
...
gulp.task("ts", function () {
  return gulp.src(tsInputFiles)
    .pipe(tsProject())
    .js
    .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/js"));
});
```

Comment: Show your `tsconfig.json`  file, are you using webpack?

Comment: I've added the `tsconfig.json`. No I'm using a gulp pipeline.

Comment: I think, you could try add `babel` to your gulp pipeline.

Comment: I added babel to my pipeline after `.js` and before `gulp.dest`, but it didn't help. What exactly should babel do?

Comment: "I receive browser errors for this." Could you tell us what are these ?

Comment: Do you want to exclude only `exports` line, or `require` as well? Which bundler/loader is used?

Comment: @KewinDousse: the error is about "exports is an unknown object, and I can't use it", but it doesn't really matter. I want TypeScript to NOT generate those lines.

Comment: @raina77ow: I want to exclude both. I don't use any bundler/loader. I add JQuery via a simple `<script src="...">` tag, I don't want it to be imported/included some way. I just need the types to be present in TypeScript.

Comment: BTW, you can exclude references from generated files with `noResolve: false` option.

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the module loading in the beginning of your typescript file, if you do not want to load any modules?

file1.ts:

```
$(function () {
});
```

If you try to compile this, you'll get an error:

```
file1.ts(2,1): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to
install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery` and
then add `jquery` to the types field in your tsconfig.
```

Run npm as told above (`npm init` first, if npm has not been initialized in the directory).

Then add `typeRoots` and `types` to tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/types" ],
    "types": [ "jquery" ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
 }
```

After that, the compiling works, and you still have the strong typing in place (jquery types applied in compilation).

Comment: This seems to work, however, how to extend an interface from a given type schema? The compiler always fails with "Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations."

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use `TypeScript` files injected directly into a HTML file via `gulp` task (compiled into es5).
At first adding `type="module"` to `<script>` helped. But then more problems appeared, so finally I've end up using this notation instead of `import`:

```
/// <reference types="@types/jquery" />
/// <reference path="my_custom_file.ts" />
/// <reference path="my_externalTypes.d.ts" />
```

and `namespace` in each of the file to separate them from each other.

That should work for a simple, small projects.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't support JavaScript modules, so you'll need to tell the TypeScript compiler that you're trying to compile code that will be run on a browser. I don't know what the rest of your project looks like, but in your configuration, try adding `"module": "es2015"` or `"module": "system"` to your configuration, while also adding an [`outFile`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) defining where you want to file to be generated :

in your tsconfig file :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "outFile": "script.js",
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: That'll generate `import` statements in JS files.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither es2015 nor system helped.

Comment: Indeed, if you're not using any bundler and don't want multiple files, then I guess you should use the outFile option, which "concatenates" (in short) the output in a single file, after resolving the module imports. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Concatenating still creates the lines in question :(